# Signing executables for Windows

Tags: windows, cryptography, executable, sign, authenticode

I develop a desktop application for use on Windows, and was wondering how I can get my executables signed so they stop showing those horrible looking warning messages about being from an unknown publisher.  I am somewhat familiar with signing binaries before releasing them.  I have a Linux port of the same program which is distributed though it's own signed repository (apt-get).

The process for signing windows executables seems extremely complicated and I can't find a simple tutorial on what to do, rather thousands of webpages describing only parts of the process, or which go into way too much depth.

I just need a quick list of steps which are necessary to sign executables under windows.  I believe it's called "authenticode".

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools see [MSFT Introduction to Code Signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#introduction_to_code_signing)

edit: you buy a certificate from a provider - most web registrars sell them.
Then simply sign the executable using the msft tools

see http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/code-signing-process.html

Comment: I have seen this link already.  It tells me why certificates are needed, and defines a few terms and lists some command line apps.  It really doesn't tell me the process of how I need to acquire this 509.X certicate it mentions.  Does it need to have special permissions, or can I generate my own wigh GPG?  This really doesn't provide a whole ton of info.

Comment: GPG is a completely different system compared to X.509 certificates - that can not be used. Self-signed X.509 certificates are also not very usable besides on your own PC or corporate environment. You have to buy a code-signing certificate from a Certificate Authority that is included in the Windows certificate store.

Comment: @Robert - or from Honest Achmed's store (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647959)

Comment: Let's see if he manages to convince Microsoft to add his root certificate ;)