# Resolve "not commonly downloaded" warning in Chrome for customers

Tags: google-chrome, malware, vendor

When customers click on a download link for one of our products they see a warning that the file is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous.

This is a false positive.

Where can we upload our files to be marked as safe by Chrome/Google as we do for all anti-virus vendors?

Answer (score 5):

You can see [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/01/all-about-safe-browsing.html) how Google does it. Apparently, signing your EXE with a proper trusted (non-self-generated) certificate helps.

Comment: I need to know how to sign the .exe - it seems this is some big secret?

Comment: If by "secret" you mean "[first hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file) on Google when searching for 'sign executable'", then yes. :p

Comment: I signed my software with a certificate I bought from symantec, and I still have the warning. Ant idea?

Comment: Same here. Signing appears to make no difference.

Comment: I have this issue with a signed software !! with EV signature !!!