# What is the simplest modern way to sign a packaged executable?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, windows-10, executable

**Before this gets marked as duplicate** I have found answers at several sources ([source 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84847/2512078), [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252226/2512078), [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18211594/2512078)) however all of them either use `makecert.exe`, `signtool.exe`, or fail to mention proper workflow of the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` command in PowerShell 4.

*Could you describe the certificate signing process to an absolute novice?*

The process should be free and understandable for someone who has nothing to work with but an executable they made and a domain (in my case purchased from [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com)).

The end goal of this is to remove the "Unknown Publisher" warning from all of my applications that I have made for other people to use. Usually these are packaged by PyInstaller as single-file applications, however I plan to expand this to full installable applications with one main executable in the future.

[image: UAC Example]

The file that I will be testing this on is my [Bonjour Installer](https://github.com/spikespaz/bonjour-installer/releases/tag/v1.0) that simply finds the iTunes installer from Apple's website, extracts only Bonjour, and runs only the installer for the system architecture.

I should also mention that I am doing this on **Windows 10**.

Comment: This is literally a duplicate question. Attempt one of the methods then ask a specific question about specific problems that you have implementing that method.

Comment: @EBGreen This is a question asking for something different than the one I linked, did you see the disclaimer? I am asking what workflow should be used in my specific scenario, not just for the names of commands as given in the other post that both of us linked.

Comment: That answer covers creating a cert and using that cert to sign code. That is the workflow for signing code.

Comment: Did you follow the steps listed there?

Comment: @EBGreen No, because the actual answer at all of these is deprecated. Not to mention, the docs linked in the first source results in a 404. How do I get `signtool`? I installed the SDK linked, and it doesn't appear anywhere on my hard drive.

Comment: I would start with Powershell and Get-Help New-SelfSignedCertificate