# Where get whitelist uac binaries?

Tags: uac, whitelist

Where I may get  whitelist uac binaries for windows 7. I am try  looked in msdn, google,  but nothing found. 
I know about this lists [1](http://withinwindows.com/2009/02/05/list-of-windows-7-beta-build-7000-auto-elevated-binaries/) and  [2](http://withinwindows.com/2009/05/02/short-windows-7-release-candidate-auto-elevate-white-list/), but how he build them...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signing a Windows exe file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know about this lists [1](http://withinwindows.com/2009/02/05/list-of-windows-7-beta-build-7000-auto-elevated-binaries/) and  [2](http://withinwindows.com/2009/05/02/short-windows-7-release-candidate-auto-elevate-white-list/), but how he build them...

Answer (score 0):

If UAC is enabled, you cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. See [FAQ: Why can’t I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510) for more information. Excerpt:

> If it were possible to mark an application to run with
> silently-elevated privileges, what would become of all those apps out
> there with LUA bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked to silently elevate.
> How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To silently
> elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user
> applications will continue to require and run with full administrative
> permissions unnecessarily.