# How to install SignTool.exe for Windows 10

Tags: signtool

How to install SignTool.exe in Visual Studio 2015 for Windown 10?
I tried to build my project but the program threw an error :

> Error     An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found.

Comment: try to take a look in %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin if the tool is existing. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/11/18/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found.aspx.

Comment: @JrTabuloc I'm using VS 2015 and I have not signtool.exe in %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

Comment: Windows 10 WDK is installed by default on "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10" path. Try to take look in "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86" if the tool is existing.

Comment: Also you could try to use "%WindowsSdkDir%\bin\x86" or "%WindowsSdkDir%\bin\x64" paths. If you haven't "%WindowsSdkDir%" environment variable in command line shell, you can call something like "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\vc\vcvarsall.bat" for it.

Comment: @hal  I found signtool.exe and copy into %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin . I tried build solution again but it threw an new error 
`Error  An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\LotusGenCode.exe. SignTool Error: Invalid option: /fd LotusGenCode  
`

Comment: I found on `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx` page that this flag is not supported for Windows Vista and earlier. I think that you found too old version of SignTool.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You need to install the Windows 10 SDK.

1. Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 contains it already, but it is not installed by default. You should go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features, find Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and select "Change".

Visual Studio 2015 setup will start. Select "Modify".

In Visual Studio components list find "Universal Windows App Development Tools", open the list of sub-items and select "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240)".

[Windows 10 SDK in VS 2015 Update 1 Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9A5K.png)

2. Of cause you can install Windows 10 SDK directly from Microsoft: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=698771

As josant already wrote - when the installation finishes you will find the SignTool.exe in the folders:

- x86 -> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
- x64 -> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\

Comment: For what it's worth, if all you need is signtool.exe, in the From SDK 10 installer, the only Feature you need to enable is the **Windows Software Development Kit** saves you around 400MB. Not much, but it's something.

Comment: Latest figure today for Visual Studio 2017 required 6.28 GB for this tool.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86` |  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64`

Comment: It's available on chocolatey if you're using it:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/windows-sdk-10.0

Comment: Mine was at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit

Answer (score 88):

If you **only** want SignTool and really want to minimize the install, here is a way that I just reverse-engineered my way to:

1. Download the `.iso` file from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk (current download link is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=2022797) The `.exe` download **will not work**, since it's an online installer that pulls down its dependencies at runtime.
2. Unpack the `.iso` with a tool such as [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/).
3. Install the `Installers/Windows SDK Signing Tools-x86_en-us.msi` file - it's only 388 KiB large. For reference, it pulls in its files from the following `.cab` files, so these are also needed for a standalone install:

   - `4c3ef4b2b1dc72149f979f4243d2accf.cab` (339 KiB)
   - `685f3d4691f444bc382762d603a99afc.cab` (1002 KiB)
   - `e5c4b31ff9997ac5603f4f28cd7df602.cab` (389 KiB)
   - `e98fa5eb5fee6ce17a7a69d585870b7c.cab` (1.2 MiB)

There we go - you will now have the `signtool.exe` file and companions in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64` (replace `x64` with `x86`, `arm` or `arm64` if you need it for another CPU architecture.)

---

It is also possible to commit  `signtool.exe` and the other files from this folder into your version control repository if want to use it in e.g. CI scenarios. I have tried it and it seems to work fine.

(*All* files are probably not necessary since there are also some other `.exe` tools in this folder that might be responsible for these dependencies, but I am not sure which ones could be removed to make the set of files even smaller. Someone else is free to investigate further in this area. :) I tried to just copy `signtool.*` and that didn't work, so at least some of the other files are needed.)

Comment: Perfect. I just needed the signtool. None of the extra fluff. By the way, right-clicking the .cab files and selecting `install` didn't work for me. I got the error `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Another option if [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe) are being used, is it to add the workload "Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce.MSBuild" to the installer via: `vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --add Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce.MSBuild`. After the installation the signtool.exe is under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe`.

Answer (score 55):

Here's where you'll find it:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In my case, I had to add this to Path environment variable to get Click to Sign working in Digicert. Commenting for anyone else who faced an issue where they were unable to sign using Digicert click to sign even after following their documentation.

Answer (score 39):

Best solution end of 2020:

Just download Windows 10 SDK from Microsoft here:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=698771

In setup, choose only **Windows App Certification App** (it's *only* 184 MB)

[image]

You can find signtool.exe here:

```
%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
```

Cheers!

Comment: As of 10.0.22621 signtool ended up in %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Windows Kits\10\App \Certification Kit\

Answer (score 23):

As per the comments in the question... On Windows 10 Signtool.exe and other SDK tools have been moved into **"%programfiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\"**.

Typical path to signtool on Windows 10.

- 32 bit = **"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe"**
- 64 bit = **"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe"**

Tools for SDK 8.0 and 8.1 also reside in the "Windows Kits" folder.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  How do you install it in the first place? There is nothing in those folders on my system - even with Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 10):

Another answer from 2021.

You might not need Windows SDK at all. If you have **VS-2019** installed, you might already have signtool in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe`

NOTE: The good thing about *this particular* `signtool` version (compared to the Windows SDK one), is that it's self-contained, and does not need all the dll's next to it (`mssign32.dll`, `wintrust.dll` etc, which usually lie around in Windows SDK folders).

You can even add this file to your source code repo (just one file), since this tool hasn't changed since 2016.

P.S. I had this signtool even without "ClickOnce publishing" component installed in my Visual Studio Community Edition.

Answer (score 8):

Location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\signtool.exe
```

Comment: Only when you have installed Windows 10 SDK.

Answer (score 3):

to install just the signingtools from the winsdksetup.exe (available at the same url as the windows sdk iso mentioned above) this is an option to, straight from the Dockerfile i'm working in:
RUN powershell Start-Process winsdksetup.exe -ArgumentList '/features OptionId.SigningTools', '/q', '/ceip off', '/norestart', -NoNewWindow -Wait

so if you're in windows then that'd be:
winsdksetup.exe /features OptionId.SigningTools

winsdksetup /h gives you the options, so i won't summarise them here.
I include the dockerfile snippet, as that is what i started my day looking for the solution for.

Answer (score 3):

**You don't have to install the Signtool. It might already be there.**

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and search for `signtool.exe`. In my system I found it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool`

No matter which version of Windows you are using, the above signtool will solve your purpose.

Comment: As far as I know, signtool.exe will be already present only if you installed Windows SDK or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

In 2019, this is a quite recent link from Microsoft about how to obtain this tool:

> The SignTool tool is a command-line tool that digitally signs files,
>   verifies signatures in files, or time stamps files. For information
>   about why signing files is important, see Introduction to Code
>   Signing. The tool is installed in the \Bin folder of the Microsoft
>   Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) installation path.
>
> SignTool is available as part of the Windows SDK, which you can
>   download from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84091.

I only needed signtool, so I chose the minimal I came up with and signtool.exe is now in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe`

[image: Installation selection]

Microsoft article link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS Express 2015, just go to your control panel --> programs and features --> select vs 2015 --> click change, then in the VS Express installer select 'Modify' --> select Publishing tools, and finish.  Once setup completes the changes you will be able to create your installer.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features, find Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and select "Change".
Visual Studio 2015 setup will start. Select "Modify".

In Visual Studio components list, open the list of sub-items and select  "ClickOnce Publication Tools" and  "Windows 10 SDK" too.

Answer (score 0):

I did a modify with the Visual Studio from Control Panel, Programs and Features.  The SDK was not at first apparent so I installed the Common Tools which lo and behold did include the SDK Update 3.

Comment: Did you have faced the issue described in the question and did what you describe fix that? Please clarify that in your answer. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's available many, many places, depending upon what is installed:
On my box, every one except the v6.0A SDK version supports the /fd option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) is available as part of the Windows SDK (which comes with [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://myprodscussu1.app.vssubscriptions.visualstudio.com/Downloads?PId=1927)). Make sure to select the "[ClickOnce Publishing Tools](http://www.benedykt.net/content/repository/2015/08/ClickOnce-Publishing-Tools.png)" from the feature list during the installation of Visual Studio 2015 to get the SignTool.

[image: ClickOnce Publishing Tools]

Once Visual Studio is installed you can run the `signtool` command from the [Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx).

By default (on Windows 10) the SignTool will be installed in:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe`

Answer (score 0):

For me in 2021 the signtool.exe was here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64"   or in:   x86

and not under: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit
even if I have this folder and may files in it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue using this tool in a restrictive Azure DevOps Pipelines environment, where I couldn't even expand `PATH` or call any tools from an absolute path outside of the ADO build directories, meaning in this case anything from `C:\Program Files (x86)\`

My solution was to package it as a *Secure File* in ADO Pipelines' `Library` -> `Secure Files` section, allow my pipeline to access the file via its security settings, then download it as a build task and run it via a powershell task.

[image: Secure files location]

In the example below, I just query the help with the `/?` command. Just replace that with whatever command you want to use.

```
      - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        displayName: "Signtool Download"
        name: MSSignTool
        inputs:
          secureFile: 'signtool.exe'

      - task : PowerShell@2
        displayName: "Run Signtool"
        inputs:
         targetType: "inline"
         script: $(MSSignTool.secureFilePath) /?
```

Warning 1: I'm not sure what dependencies are required for `signtool.exe` to work standalone, or if it even has any. The Windows 10 SDK and ADK was already installed in this build environment. If querying the help causes the tool to fail or crash, make sure one or both of those are installed. Hopefully you will have access to something like [`choco`](https://chocolatey.org/) to install any missing dependencies.

Warning 2: **Be careful if copying those code segments**. ADO is pretty strict with dynamic whitespace, so if your spacing is off it will brick your whole pipelines file until you adjust the spacing to its correct position.