# How to install SignTool.exe for VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, signtool

After upgrade to VS 2017 i got 
"Error An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found."
But only using MSbuild on the Visual Studio publish there's no problem.

I already checked folder 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin"
and in fact there's no SignTool.exe present.
But there was before installing VS2017, any ideas?

I followed this issue but no luck 
[How to install SignTool.exe for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869552/how-to-install-signtool-exe-for-windows-10)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Signtool is included with the Windows 10 SDK

1. Open Visual Studio installer.
2. Switch to the "Individual Components" tab
3. Choose the version of the SDK that suits your needs.

[image]

Multiple copies may be installed.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool>` 
This is where its there in my System.

Answer (score 4):

Start Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 then it is in the path variable
[signtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRgJJ.png)

That seems to do the trick, now the problem is with setup.bin file.

error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in csproj folder

Answer (score 2):

The all solutions didn't worked for me ; finally i just copied ***signtool.exe*** to the project folder and then worked.  You can download the signtool.exe from internet or install **Windows 10 SDK** by **visual studio installer** and then copy from  **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool"**.

Answer (score 1):

I found it under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin

It could be because it was there before the vs2017 installation.

It doesn't harm to check :)

Comment: In my case it doesn't appear to be there! Even if I copy it there it doesn´t work either! I think is like you say, it probably was already there, unnistalling VS2015 must've broken some enviroment variables. i've copy the folder to my project folder, and solved it

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I had with this was that the path variable wasn't set up. I ran

set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool";%PATH%

in the Developer Command window before trying to sign anything.

If you do it this way you will need to run the set path every time you want to use it unless you add it to the path environment variable.
I hope this helps.