# Run App Blocked Due To Certificate Revocation

Tags: windows-10, certificate, uac, certificate-revocation

I'm running Windows 10 Pro with the latest updates. Just today I started having an issue with a piece of legacy software: Wise (used to make installers). When I try to run it, I get the below error:

[image]

"This app has been blocked for your Protection" "An administrator has blocked you from running this app."

Running the app as admin does not resolve the issue.

After doing some poking around, I believe the issue is the certificate. It is SHA-1, expired 10 years ago, and is marked "This certificate has been revoked by its certification authority".

That is all well and good, except this vendor is effectively gone. So I can't get a new version of the software. How do I run this program in the mean time?

Edit: Running the program through an admin command prompt seems to work. Is that the only option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with a signed executable having its certificate revoked, so here's what I did to unsign the executable using the Widnows SDK tool SignTool.exe.

1. Download the .iso file from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk
2. Mount the .iso, browse to Installers directory and install this component: Windows SDK Signing Tools-x86_en-us.msi (it's like 7 MB installed and you don't need to install the whole SDK, only that component)
3. CMD as admin, navigate to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64
4. Run this (for your .exe): signtool.exe remove /s "Path to file you want to un-sign here"
   (e.g. signtool.exe remove /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Altiris\Wise\WiseClient.exe")
5. Executable should now be unsigned.

Ref: [How to install SignTool.exe for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869552/how-to-install-signtool-exe-for-windows-10) and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool