# How to sign a console application in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

That's probably a stupid question, but I've been banging my head on the walls over this.
The [numerous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [resources](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/vssigning.aspx) I have found online all point out to some "signing" tab in the projects properties. 
The steps are supposed to be:

1. Select the target project in the solution explorer.
2. Click "properties" from the "Project" menu.

The project designer should appear with its long lost signing tab.
[image: project designer]

However, 
here's what I get:

[image]
[image]

As it is plain to see, this looks nothing like the first screenshot. Can someone point to me what I'm doing wrong? Does this view even exist in the Community Edition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it from the command line if you don't get an answer on how to use VS.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file

Comment: Thanks! I'd really like to automate this, otherwise I'll go for a .bat fix!

Comment: You can always use Build step or events to call signtool directly.

Comment: The documentation you link to is about a .NET project. An ordinary desktop program, regardless of subsystem, is not a .NET project. Hence the difference in dialogs.

Comment: Oooh, that makes sense. So there's no way to sign console applications automatically?