# Applying code signing for 7zip SFX (self extracting exe)

Tags: exe, 7zip, sfx

I have code signing applied to the windows exe.

And then we create an SFX (self extracting exe) with that windows exe and a json data file using the following commands.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z abc.7z "C:/xampp/htdocs/path/test.dat"

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z abc.7z "C:/xampp/htdocs/path/test.exe"
```

But when we try to download this sfx exe, we are getting warning from the browser and also showing confirmation to proceed with the installation when trying to install since there is no publisher info.

How can I apply code signing to the sfx exe created with the 7zip??

Comment: See [Using SignTool to Sign a File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388170)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing a Windows EXE file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file)