# 7Z SFX Unknow Publisher

Tags: batch-file, manifest, sfx

i make some 7z sfx and working on my pc after make this sfx but after move to another computer after download and run this sfx get me this error Unknow Publisher and security message !

i read some post oin stackowerflow for sfx manifest and mt.exe to fix this problem but i cant know this !

for example this 7z sfx check laptop battery health and save html report on desktop :

`https://lapfix.ir/used-laptop-test-file/Battery.exe`

please help me to fix this problem

Regards , Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what this has to do with [tag:batch-file]s.  You may be able to use a batch file to run a powershell command, but you would have to run it separately from the `.exe`, e.g. `PowerShell -NoP "Unblock-File -Path C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Battery.exe"`.

Comment: i created batch file after uploadin on web site click on download button show command in batch file and wont downloaded , inside battery.exe have powercg.exe and sfx run this file by specific command ,  <code> PowerShell -NoP "Unblock-File -Path C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Battery.exe" </code> this command don,t show Unknow Publisher on my computer but i want after make sfx archive on any computer don,t ask Unknow Publisher !

Comment: Windows has security in place for downloaded files with certain extensions, and one of those is `.exe`. Ideally you will need a certificate, possible duplicate of [Signing a Windows EXE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file), _which is also linked to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40633643)_.