# Exe files and Windows SmartScreen

Tags: java, windows, exe, smartscreen

I am trying to make a .exe file from a .jar file, and it is working fine.  My only problem is that when trying to run it on another computer that I didn't make it on, Windows SmartScreen says it's an unknown app and blocks it from running.  I am running Windows 10.  Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: either get it digitally signed, or disable smartscreen...

Comment: @MarcB I can't disable SmartScreen on everyone's computer!  How would I get it signed?

Comment: @Orion31 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file

Comment: @Ghost93 I looked at that and downloaded the SDK, but when opening Command Prompt, `sign` is an unknown command.

Comment: @Orion31 the command should be `signtool` and you should open the _Developer Command Prompt_

Comment: @Ghost93 I don't have Developer Command Prompt installed X_X

Comment: @Ghost93 I have been looking everywhere for this Developer Command Prompt, but it isn't anywhere on my computer.  I downloaded Windows 7 and Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: @Orion31 Do you have the .Net framework installed? Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio, and sign tool worked but it said `SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.`  Sorry for stupid questions.  I never made an exe before!