# Executable security warning on Windows

Tags: windows, rust

When I build an executable for Windows with `cargo build --release` and zip the executable file with its resources, then unzip and run it from another Windows computer, it displays a big warning about security. I never saw this warning before on Windows, even on not-so-reliable application.

The warning message says the application is unsigned and has no editor (it's in french, and it does not displays anymore since I accepted, so I can't paste it, sorry). I have to click twice to accept, then it runs the windows default antivirus.

Not sure it's really related to Rust programming, maybe more about windows executable, but **is there a way to limit this kind of security alert** when building a windows application with Cargo?

PS: I don't know where to start, sorry if I am not in the right place for this kind of question.

Comment: Can you produce the same behavior by producing an c++-executable and packing it into `.zip` archive? If so, when this behavior is not related to any language but to unpacking an executable from a `.zip` archive.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file