# Generate a certificate for .exe created by pyinstaller

Tags: python, certificate, pyinstaller

I wrote a script for my company that randomly selects employees for random drug tests. It works wonderfully, except when I gave it to the person who would use the program. She clicked on it and a message popped up asking if she trusts the program. AFter clicking run anyways, AVG flagged it two more times before it would finally load. I read someone else's comment saying to make an exception for it on the antivirus. The problem is, I wrote another program that reads other scripts and reads/writes txt files, generates excel spreadsheets and many other things. I'm really close to releasing the final product to a few select companies as a trial, and this certificate thing is going to be an issue. I code for fun, so there's a lot of lingo that goes right by me. Can someone point me in the right direction where I can get some information on creating a trusted program?

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a whole long process to obtain a digital certification. You need one to be issued by a certification authority. Microsoft appears to have a [docs page on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537361(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#obtaining-certification).

After you have the certification, you'd need to sign your `.exe` file after it's been created using a tool like [SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You may find more useful and detailed answers than I can provide you in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252226/13591094), as I actually only know quite little about this whole process and can only redirect you to those who know more. I'd suggest you look through what I have listed here before asking me any more, since I probably know about as much as you do past this point.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is having this problem, I stumbled on a solution that works for me.

I created an Install Wizard using Inno Setup. Before I could install the software (My drug test program), it got flagged, asking me if I trust the software. I clicked "run anyway" and my antivirus flagged it two more times. After the program was installed. it never flagged me again. Since my main program will probably be used by 100-200 people, I'm completely fine having to do that procedure once. However, for a more "professional" result, it's probably work investing in certificates.