# How to compile with py2exe to single file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

I need to compile my python code to .exe for user distribution. I was trying `pyinstaller` - works fine, but Win Defender was blocking generated .exe as virus. I tried [several things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800999/10012449) to avoid it but unsuccessfully.

So now I try to use py2exe utility. I managed it run like this (this should be onefile):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    console = ["myApp.py"],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Compiles ok, I can even run it from dist folder, but **as soon as I move .exe to different place it gives me error**:

`AttributeError: module 'http.client' has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'. Did you mean: 'HTTPConnection'?`

Http is module used in myApp.

This is the content of dist folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `auto-py-to-exe` and get a GUI to do the task. It allows you to make a single file. Just install using `pip install auto-py-to-exe` and run using the `auto-py-to-exe` command

Comment: OK, but this is only GUI for pyinstaller and as I mentioned, pyinstaller output is blocked as virus by Win Defender.