# How can someone become a well-known software manufacturer in the Microsoft ecosystem?

Tags: windows

When I install a program what I create, windows warns me that the software manufacturer cannot be verified. I tried to look it up but couldn't find any relevant guidance. How can someone become a well-known software manufacturer in the Microsoft ecosystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally Windows warns users [(UAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) when installing/executing a program which hasn't digitally signed.

> Code signing is used on Windows and Mac OS X to authenticate software on first run, ensuring that the software has not been maliciously tampered with by a third-party distributor or download site.

More about [code signing.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing)

1. You have to purchase a certificate first.
   It will cost you about 500 USD per year.
   You can purchase certificate from leading companies like "Digicert", "COMODO" etc.
   Check [prices](https://www.digicert.com/order/order-1.php) (@digicert)
2. After purchasing a certificate, you have to sign your program with a 'sign tool' - You can find out how to sign your program in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file).

After these steps Windows will recognise your program as authentic. And that means, it won't warn users (as an unknown publisher) when running/installing your software.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This clarified the overall picture.