# How to assure windows that my app is safe to run?

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

For my college project, I created a MapGenerator to create maps for the project. It is a group project, so I converted my `.java` files to `.exe` using Launch4J.
I then shared it to my friends using Google Drive. But then, while downloading, my friends said that Google said that the download is potentially dangerous. They just selected "Keep" and continued the download. The problem came when Windows doesn't let them to run that app at all. We know it's a safe application and does nothing wrong other than creating `.csv` files.

So, is there any way to assure Windows that this is a safe application and allow it to run the application?

PS: *I use IntelliJ without gradle or maven, just IntelliJ (if this is a necessary info)*

Answer (score 0):

You can select the exe you want to run --> Click properties --> Under the general tab beside the security option --> check the unblock. Then it should definitely run

To have your exe like other software , you have to get your exe signed but I don't know how to do it. The solution I gave is a duct tape glue solution and I thought it would help.

You can check this link for more info:-
[Signing a Windows EXE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file)

Comment: Another way of making to easily run by any computer is to get the exe file signed although I don't know how to do it myself.

Comment: Is it possible that even without doing all these the app is safe to run?

Comment: Like all the software we install, we never do all these steps and are safe normally, so what did that do to let it run without blocking?

Comment: Just as I said to do that you have to get your exe signed but I don't know how to do it.