# Autoupdater is falsely detected as virus

Tags: c++, antivirus, virus

My autoupdater gets falsely detected as a virus

This app is ran by another app that checks if a new version is avaiable then it closes itselft and opens this,and this is the code that gets flagged

the code

```
class DownloadProgress : public IBindStatusCallback {
public:
    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID&, void**) {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) {
        return 1;
    }
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void) {
        return 1;
    }
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnStartBinding(DWORD dwReserved, IBinding* pib) {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPriority(LONG* pnPriority) {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLowResource(DWORD reserved) {
        return S_OK;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnStopBinding(HRESULT hresult, LPCWSTR szError) {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBindInfo(DWORD* grfBINDF, BINDINFO* pbindinfo) {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDataAvailable(DWORD grfBSCF, DWORD dwSize, FORMATETC* pformatetc, STGMEDIUM* pstgmed) {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnObjectAvailable(REFIID riid, IUnknown* punk) {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnProgress(ULONG ulProgress, ULONG ulProgressMax, ULONG ulStatusCode, LPCWSTR szStatusText)
    {
        std::wcout << ulProgress << " of " << ulProgressMax << '\n';
        return S_OK;
    }
};

int main() {
    DownloadProgress downloadStatus;

    URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"https://github.com/Denellyne/PCXSense/releases/download/Latest/PCXSense.rar", L"PCXSense.rar", 0, static_cast<IBindStatusCallback*>(&downloadStatus));
    system("unrar x -o+ PCXSense.rar");
    DeleteFile(L"PCXSense.rar");
    system("PCXSense.exe");

    return 0;
}
```

Tried changing the code,initially it had Taskkill but I removed it

Comment: "detected as a virus" by what?  how?  why?

Comment: If you look at what your program does it looks a lot like what a virus downloader might do. Is it a particular antivirus that detects this or many? Check at virustotal.

Comment: There are 20 Antivirus that flag it as such including Microsoft, and its flagged mostly as a trojan

Comment: Digitally signing the code can sometimes help with heuristic detection, at least it did a while back with our launcher when it looked very much like a virus. You might try moving the download to your main program and then have it call a stub to decompress the archive and relaunch the program. Integrating the decompression code into the executable instead of using system to launch unrar might help too.

Comment: How can you digitally sign the code? Don't I need to pay for that?

Comment: [Signing a Windows EXE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file) has a lot of information. You can use a self-signed certificate locally during development but you'll need to use a real one if you plan to distribute your executables.