# Self-signed certificate - unable to open certificate

Tags: certificate, clickonce, code-signing, setup-deployment

I need a self-signed certificate to create a ClickOnce application in C++. I'm a real novice at deployment, so I'm following Stack Overflow question *[How to create a self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)*.

Here's the command sequence I've used

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Watersteward" -ss CA -sr CurrentUser -sky signature -sv WaterSteward.pvk WaterSteward.cer
makecert -pe -n "CN=Watersteward" -sky signature -ic WaterSteward.cer -iv WaterSteward.pvk -sv WsSPC.pvk WsSPC.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk WsSPC.pvk -spc WsSPC.cer -pfx WsSPC.pfx
mage -s Alpine.exe.manifest -CertFile WsSPC.pfx
```

The last command to sign the manifest fails with the message:

> Unable to open certificate "WsSPC.pfx": The specified network password is not correct.

I added *WaterSteward.cer* to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities after creation and before going on to the next step.

During each step above, a dialog popped up asking for a password. In each case I clicked *None* (I've also tried it with  `-n "CN=mydomain\mylogin"` and giving my password in the dialogs).

Answer (score 1):

I would just run Visual Studio, go to the project properties, go to the *Signing* tab, and click *Create Test Certificate*. Be sure to check the box to sign the application, and to go to *Security* and turn on the ClickOnce security settings.

Answer (score 0):

This blog helped me a lot :
[How to create certificates for development](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development)

- Instead of providing no password I provided a password in each prompt.
- I created the certificate and its private key on the hard drive (second option mentioned in the blog)

The last step in signing the manifest - which is not mentioned in the blog - was straightforward:
in your case

> mage -s Alpine.exe.manifest -CertFile WsSPC.pfx