# Internet Explorer blocks self-signed ActiveX

Tags: activex, certificate, self-signed, makecert, signtool

I have create a self-signed certificate and signed my ActiveX. I followed the steps in this topic. ([How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows))

One difference is that my executable files come in MSI package. So I used signtool to sign the MSI file and all other DLLs/Exe inside the MSI.

I imported the certificate to trusted root store. When I clicked download the MSI, I could see that the publisher is correct, and it wasn't 'Unknown Publisher'. IE allows me to download and run MSI file,but when I tried to call my ActiveX,IE blocks it. (Error: Automation server can't create object)

I found some websites mentioned that I have to set CN="my web site URL", what should I put for "localhost"?

My activeX will be used in intranet network,so I don't want to buy cert from those CA.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Aing: Is your ActiveX marked "safe for scripting"?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(VS.85).aspx