# How to create a certificate for signing a Silverlight xap

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

I have a silverlight app that will be installed OOB with full trust and hence i want to create a certificate to sign the app. Since I'm going to have full control of the clients where the app will be installed I don't need to buy a certificate, because I know that I can create one and install it in the Trusted Root Certification Authority. Can someone please post a step by step on how to create the certificate so it can be used to sign the XAP.

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great post in StackOverflow that goes over the process of how to create a CA and use that CA to generate the certificate. Here's the link:

[How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)