# Windows7 boot option to allow unsigned drivers ignored

Tags: windows-7, driver, signing

I'm learning Windows kernel mode driver development.  I've written a small test driver that I can successfully register, unregister, load and unload under Windows 7 32bit Ultima edition running under a VM in VirtualBox.

My host is Windows 7 64bit Home Premium edition.

The driver, compiled for 64 bit, will not load under Windows 7 Home edition.  I keep getting a rejection noticed that this version of windows does not allow unsigned drivers.

I've tried two things:

1. I've used the F8 boot option to allow unsigned drivers (didn't work)
2. I run a CMD as administrator and execute the following two commands

   bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS

   bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON

and rebooted.  My desktop shows me in "TestMode" but still I get same rejection noticed.

Can anyone help me out here or explain if there is an additional step for Home edition?

----{ update }----
After pouring through tons of MSDN stuff, it would appear my solution lies in self signing the driver I created.  The DDK I downloaded does not appear to have the tool chain to do self signing.  I've downloaded WinDDK-7600.16385.1.  But what is so strange is that my Windows Ultima Edition happily loads my driver if I simply F8 @ boot time and tell it to allow unsigned drivers.

Comment: OT: <insert snide remark here about what happens when you give your software freedom up to a 3rd party>

Comment: trust me, Nathan, in the office where I work I'm called the Linux bigot (for good reason), this post and my frustration with Microsoft products only helps my case.  As such, I'm currently learning Windows kernel mode driver development for a project that needs Windows OS support in the form of a Kernel driver.  We have a custom hardware device we communicate with over USB that we need to send data too uninterrupted at precise intervals.  Using windows timer and timer queues is not good enough for our needs.  Any side thoughts on this are welcome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You might try the [Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider](http://www.ngohq.com/home.php?page=dseo).** It's supported on 64-bit versions of Windows 7, and reports that I've seen confirm that it does indeed work on the "Home Premium" edition.

[image: Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider screenshot]

> 1. Download the application from the link below. Right click on it and
>      choose "Run as administrator". Inside
>      its main menu, press on the “Enable
>      Test Mode” button and follow the
>      instructions on the screen. This will
>      enable TESTSIGNING mode, which allows
>      unverified system files to be loaded.
> 2. Now all you have to do is to add the unverified signature to the
>      required system files. To do so press
>      on the “Sign a System File” button
>      from the main menu, and enter specific
>      filename including full path. For
>      example: if ATITool64.sys from
>      C:\Windows\System32\drivers refuses to
>      load due to driver signature
>      enforcement, you should type:
>      “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\ATITool64.sys”,
>      and if you would like to sign more
>      than a single file, just repeat this
>      procedure until you’re done, and
>      finally reboot.
>
> After you enabled Test Mode and added
>   signatures to the required system
>   files, they should bypass Windows’s
>   driver signature enforcement and load
>   without any issues. However, if for
>   some reason you are interested to
>   revert it, you can re-launch the
>   application, choose “Disable Test
>   Mode” from the main menu, and reboot.
>   If you encounter issues or having
>   questions, feel free to post it on our
>   forums.
>
> **Note:** DSEO requires administrative
>   privileges (Run as administrator).

It even allows you to remove the watermark from your desktop!

Comment: ya know, I ran across that utility but I didn't trust it because the web site I saw it on, had the ear marks of a site loaded with viruses and what not.... I may use this as a last resort.  I can find nothing on MSDN.  I also repeated the steps in my post with TESTSIGNING OFF and still not working..  I'd like to find the "right" way to do this before as well as understand why Home Edition is apparently blocked.

Comment: @Eric: Yeah, you won't find it on MSDN. This is officially **not supported** in the "Home" editions. This website doesn't look too sketchy to me, and the utility is well-supported/reviewed across the web. I'm not sure I can give you an answer *why* the "Home" editions are blocked, but I suppose it's because they can be. The typical home user isn't doing driver development and therefore doesn't have a need for this feature. Allowing it is a possible security hole, and people have been clamoring for years that Windows security sucks. No one's ever happy.

Comment: when you say "officially not supported" can you provide a link on Microsoft's site to this effect?  I'm inclined to believe you & accept this as the answer but looking for a little more "official" words.  To your point about Home edition used for development, laptop was purchased with this version of Windows pre-loaded at a closeout price so upgrading to PRO entails giving M$ more $$ which seems a bit ridiculous for everything else I use this computer for (that does not need PRO).  Do I need PRO to do driver development should be the question, right?

Comment: @Eric: No idea where to find that link. I'm sure you can search around and find something to that effect, but disabling driver signing isn't much talked about by Microsoft *anyway*. Finding more specific details is like finding a needle in a haystack. My guess is the best you can do is one of the MVPs on their forums saying something to that effect. I'm willing to bet unsigned driver installations are unsupported, too, but I *know* they are on Home editions. I'm just out of the business of proving things; I'm more interested in making them work. Maybe someone else will come along who can.

Comment: it's actually the only solution that works for me (win7 x64)

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use that tool. Just test sign the driver with your own personal certificate with the signtool in the DDK.

Comment: **makecert** + **signtool** + export cert to .PFX format and add certificate to Windows.

Comment: Technet article on [signing a driver package](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919238(v=ws.10).aspx). You'll need both the DDK and the SDK to get all the tools.