# How do I use unsigned driver on windows 7/8/8.1(especially 64 bit)

Tags: windows, automation, driver

I'd like to automate installing unsigned drivers that need to be tested.
I hear if I use gui-auto to bypass the driver warning prompts it still refuses to actually use it.

Security isn't an issue. Automation is(f8 option is useless to me, though might be useful to others). We are using Ultimate/Enterprise but others may be using Home editions).

There doesn't seem to be a full answer especially for recent os that I can find(many answers are followed by someone claiming they don't work).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928721/windows7-boot-option-to-allow-unsigned-drivers-ignored

Comment: Can Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider be used via command line? it doesn't seem like it.I'd hate to add more gui auto. Plus it looks like it doesn't support windows 8.

Comment: I don't believe you're going to find a "it warns me with a GUI which I need to automatically click OK to" solution. Instead look into the `DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS` and `TESTSIGNING` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows 8, use the following hack

http://www.fotoclubinc.com/blog/how-to-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-to-allow-installation-of-windows-7-printer-drivers-on-windows-8/

http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

For windows 7,

Open a command prompt as an admin and type

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS

bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

See security risk warning above.

If it doesn't work for whatever reason you can just remove loadoptions with bcedit and switch testsigning off.

```
bcdedit /deletevalue loadoptions

bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```