# Stop detect my application as a virus

Tags: c#, virus

I make an application that, when you run it, will put the .exe in Startup. I have this code for that:

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

rkApp.SetValue("smartAppointment", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

Will creat a registery for the application to start with the Windows, but there is a problem, some antivirus will detect my application as a virus.

How I can stop the antivirus to detect my application as a virus ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think any way of having an application automatically attempt to run at startup will be flagged as virus like behavior by any anti-virus system.  Just tell your users to approve the change when your solution is installing.

Unless (of course) you are trying to write a virus.

In that case stop.

Comment: Is not a virus, is an application for appointments. Application will start with the Windoews and will announce your appointments.

Comment: As others have said, you application needs to be digitally signed to do this the "right" way.  You may also have more luck if switch to administrator identity first (this will pop a warning to the user if they are not running as administrator).

Answer (score 1):

Is your application digitally signed? If not you should try signing your application (you need a public certificate, but that costs money)

[Application signing/verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280435/application-signing-verification)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run at startup, the generally preferred way is to run it as a windows service.

If you need a gui as well, then you should have a gui that talks to the windows service that hosts your application.

Comment: But wouldn't you still need to start the GUI part somehow, possibly through registry?

Comment: `the generally preferred way is to run it as a windows service` That is not true: Background services that don't need to interact with the user -> service, GUI programm that does not need to run if no user is logged in and/or have be be run under the users account (or that can run multiple times in multiple sessions, think about a terminal server) -> Autorun

Comment: Actually, your statement is not true. This is extremely common in the *nix space and windows isn't that different for this kind of task.  The user stated they needed a service that would remind a person of events. Why would you run a full gui all the time to do this?  You wouldn't. This is a classic example of a windows service. You would need a gui to manage the things he wants notifications for, but the notifications themselves and the scheduling and timing and all that are PERFECT for a service. This is one of the things remoting and WCF are meant for.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your installer (MSI) would set the "launch application at startup" registry setting however I think that if your application is digitally signed with an authenticode signature then this problem will disappear.