# Certificated Installers and Executables on Okuma OSP Controls

Tags: okuma

What does the process look like to make sure our Thinc App installer can run on older and new OSP controls?
I'm concerned in getting the security right so that both the installer and application can run smoothly to for the operator and not have security issues.

Greg

Comment: There is plenty of information available on supporting older versions of Windows with modern development tools. If you are creating a .NET application, target framework version 4.0 and it will run on Windows XP SP3 (the last, most up-to-date, version of XP). There is no issue running a .NET 4.0 app on later versions of the CLR. If you really want to take advantage of the newer language features, look for nuget packages to help you. What security issues are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Scott.
Like the "Windows Protected your PC" because the app is unrecognized.  Maybe this isn't a problem on the latest OSP controls and has been turned off.
I was wanting to make sure if I used a signed certificate for the app that wouldn't cause a problem or if it was even needed.

Comment: Is Windows Defender turned on in the latest OSP controls?
https://www.techjunkie.com/windows-protected-your-pc-disable-smartscreen/

Comment: They have Windows 10 LTSB, so yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5280435/2596334 Signing your app is not necessary, although it will make for a better user experience.