# How do I add a CRL address to a self-signed CA certificate?

Tags: security, code-signing

This is an extension question to:

[how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows/201277#201277)

To take this further, if I have created a CA cert, and have create a set of SPC certs, how do I go about creating revocation lists and distributing them? (note: I have no knowledge about how CRLs work, how they are distributed etc) If I were to GUESS how it all worked, I would hope that the CA cert defined some HTTP address where CRLs could be downloaded, and windows would contact that address the first time a cert chain was queried, and every time the current CRL expires... Then all I would have to do is create a signed web address that distributes certificate serial numbers...?

*EDIT: SELF ANSWERED*

For anyone else who is interested, Bouncy Castle is a Java+C# library providing a massive set of PKI Crypto APIs, including certificate generation.

Their sample code (in their downloads) demonstrates how to generate a chained set of CA, Intermediate, and 'Personal' certificates.

What it doesnt show, is how to correctly assign an HTTP based CRL - you can do so with this code:

```
GeneralName gn = new GeneralName(new DerIA5String("http://localhost/revocationlist.crl"), 6);


GeneralNames gns = new GeneralNames(gn);
DistributionPointName dpn = new DistributionPointName(gns);
DistributionPoint distp = new DistributionPoint(dpn, null, null);

DerSequence seq = new DerSequence(distp);

v3CertGen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.CrlDistributionPoints, false, seq);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a CA certificate and some set of certificates, signed by that CA certificate. Then you can create a CRL, which would (potentially) contain IDs of revoked certificates, which were previously signed using CA certificate. Indeed you add the URL of the CRL to the CA certificate itself via the corresponding certificate extension (CRLDistributionPoint).

As you have not specified, what tools or libraries you use to generate the certificates, I can't say how the extension can be added.

PS: I'd recommend that you learn about technology *before* trying to use it. Especially when it comes to implementing security. Otherwise you will end up in situation, worse than the one of Comodo, whose sub-CAs have issued fake certs for google, yahoo and more just recently.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks

I am currently using the makecert tools that are part of Visual Studio/Platform SDK.

Absolutely agree about learning all this - this is my current goal, to understand how it all ties together, and what it can achieve. I have read all about the Comodo debacle, I can't believe they havent themselves been revoked!

Comment: @Adam Comodo is a root CA, they can't be revoked. It was one of their clients, who issued fraudlent certificates. Regarding books to read  - I strongly recommend two books: http://www.eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=1842 I read them and can highly recommend them as a basis.

Comment: @Adam regarding makecert tools - from description it doesn't seem that they let you specify CRLDistributionPoint extension. So you probably need to write some code to do generation and add needed extensions. You can use OpenSSL or you can use PKIBlackbox package of our SecureBlackbox product ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-pki.php ) for this.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.
I have written a C# tool based off Bouncy Castle libraries that generates all the certificates I need.
I will definitely be taking a look at your reading suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of crypto-147 the supplied code has changed to

```
GeneralName gn = new GeneralName(GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier, new DERIA5String(crlUrl));
GeneralNames gns = new GeneralNames(gn);
DistributionPointName dpn = new DistributionPointName(gns);
DistributionPoint distp = new DistributionPoint(dpn, null, null);
DERSequence seq = new DERSequence(distp);
certGen.addExtension(Extension.cRLDistributionPoints, false, seq);
```