# Allow Windows to execute an application with an unverified publisher

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a command line utility that I'm running via C# code on the web server. The problem is that the publisher of the utility cannot be verified (i.e. the app doesn't have a digital signature), so my code can't run the exe file without human intervention.

What is the quickest way for me to have the Windows server run only this particular exe without warning about the publisher being unverified?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

The first answer will allow you to run the exe in question (bypassing UAC) without impacting other programs

[Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191129/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-programatically)