# Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows Programatically

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, uac

There are dozens of posts questions/answers on stack and other forums about disabling/bypassing/suppressing UAC. There are solutions as well. But progmatically perhaps not. I could see only one solution [Disabling UAC programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682182/disabling-uac-programmatically) but perhaps there is not real programmatic solution given there.

Can there be a programatic solution for saving user to be prompted everytime he/she runs a program like wamp and they always have to click yes, So it would be better to tell windows that their choice is always yes. I am sure there would be as

I have found [**Here**](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616) that windows provides this facility in Task Scheduler through GUI so it must be possible through code as well.

#### Update : I have prepared a pure programmatic solution which is working. See my answer.

Comment: Why are you trying to bypass the UAC

Comment: @JakobBowyer Because wherever I have deployed my c#,mysql desktop applications (which need wamp running on system), Users get irritated of UAC dialogue when wamp is started.

Comment: that sounds like a foolish idea. What if someone exploits your software, you have already done the UAC bypass for them, your now opening up a massive damn security flaw

Comment: @JakobBowyer. I can not understand how someone would this exploit my software. It does not make any difference if some user runs an app (I am concerned with wamp) bypaasing UAC or by using UAC.

Comment: So here I am an exploit writer, I pay attention to the fact your software is selectivly disabling UAC, I decide that its the best place to drop a damn exploit, Now I have some software thats running above UAC, DROP SHELL THE PLANET.... Please always think of security

Comment: @JakobBowyer you are too aggressive to discuss. I have no security risks in a desktop application running on personal computer. Still you might be right. You can down vote you can discourage others to guide me. Thats your right. But your language and your arguments are not convincing, but just like showing a disgust. I am sorry but thats what I felt.

Comment: arguing on the internet is like playing chess with a pigeon. you may win but the pidgeon will still strut all over the board crapping and feeling like the winner

Comment: Why do you need to do this and is there no way to sandbox your problem so you don't need UAC bypass? Can you run your task within the service process instead ?

Comment: Why can't you test against it? Why do you need UAC disabled?

Comment: This question has -4, this other one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682182/disabling-uac-programmatically?lq=1 has 10. Both questions are about disabling the UAC; one of them has real answers while the other one has opinions. It's sad. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Quick description:** Make a new console/window application to run any application bypassing UAC choosing the path of your target application in this application as guided below, compile this program once, and run anytime

**Step by step**

1. Download Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll from [This link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yI4tnOLgrMtr2u0qp2VMLo_-Fi77oTF8/view?usp=sharing) => [Original Source => dllme.com](https://www.dllme.com/get/17796)
2. Make a c# application (Windows or Console) and add reference to the above dll
3. Add New Item (Application Manifest File) to your project (this application)
4. Change `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`
   to `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
5. Write following code in your program.cs file

---

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      TaskService ts = new TaskService();          
      TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
      td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
      //td.Triggers.AddNew(TaskTriggerType.Logon);          
      td.Triggers.AddNew(TaskTriggerType.Once);    // 
      string program_path = @"c:\wamp\wampmanager.exe";
      // you can have dynamic value for 'program_path'
      //even of user choice giving an interface in win-form app

      td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(program_path, null));
      ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("anyNamefortask", td);          
   }
}
```

6.Now compile and run your Application(this app)

---

Now your application (e.g WAMP) will run without prompting any UAC dialog on your desired schedule (every time your log on windows in my case)

**Sources**

Initiated from : [Can you turn off UAC for a single app?](https://superuser.com/questions/2699/can-you-turn-off-uac-for-a-single-app) and [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/99286/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-7)

Basic Idea from : [**Make Vista launch UAC restricted programs at startup with Task Scheduler**](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616)

Basic Implementation from **[Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)**

Answer (score 2):

The proper methodology wouldn't be to ignore the User Access Control (UAC) but rather test within those parameters.  That way you don't disrupt security, you instead work within it's confines.

By disabling security, you run the risk of exploits.  According to Secuna which provide several security test have noticed that small companies, lazy developer applications, and blatantly disregard for security are applications that have been focused on.

Which means your application may become a victim at some point.

The approach I would take, is test within UAC.  Ensure the proper permissions exists to carry out your task, that way it isn't constantly running with Elevated Permission.  An example may be:

```
class Elevated_Rights
{
    // Token Bool:
    private bool _level = false;

    #region Constructor:
    protected Elevated_Rights()
    {
           // Invoke Method On Creation:
           Elevate();
     }
     #endregion
     public void Elevate()
     {
           // Get Identity:
           WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

           // Set Principal
           WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

           #region Test Operating System for UAC:
           if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT ||            Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
            {
                 // False:
                 _level = false;
             }
             #endregion
             else
             {
                    #region Test Identity Not Null:
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // False:
                        _level = false;
                    }
                    #endregion
                    else
                    {
                        #region Ensure Security Role:
                        if (!(role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)))
                        {
                            // False:
                            _level = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // True:
                            _level = true;
                        }
                        #endregion
             } 
      }
}
```

Something along those lines would allow you to test against the UAC, then perform a task.  I'm not quite sure why you would like to disable the UAC, but that would be my approach.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer which is not dependent on Task Scheduler but It's not clear how to use this class in the main application!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass the protections that you gain by running as a standard user, then the better solution is to change permissions on the folder and registry key so that all users are allowed to modify your application's folder.

```
GrantAllUsersFullControlToFileOrFolder("C:\Program Files\Grobtastic");
```

with a pseudocode implementation of:

```
void  GrantAllUsersFullControlToFileOrFolder(String path)
{
    PACL oldDACL;
    PACL newDACL;    
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;

    //Get the current DALC (Discretionary Access Control List) and Security Descriptor
    GetNamedSecurityInfo(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
          nil, nil, ref oldDACL, nil, ref sd);

    //Create an SID for the "Users" group
    PSID usersSid = StringToSid("S-1-5-32-545");

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new Access Control Entry (ACE)
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
    ZeroMemory(@ea, SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions  = GENERIC_ALL;
    ea.grfAccessMode         = GRANT_ACCESS;
    ea.grfInheritance        = SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm   = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeType   = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName     = PChar(usersSID);

    // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE into the existing ACL.
    // SetEntriesInAcl takes care of adding the ACE in the correct order in the list
    SetEntriesInAcl(1, @ea, oldDACL, ref newDACL); //use LocalFree to free returned newDACL

    //Attach the new ACL as the object's new DACL
    SetNamedSecurityInfo(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          nil, nil, newDACL, nil);

    LocalFree(HLOCAL(sd));
    LocalFree(HLOCAL(newDACL));
    FreeSid(usersSID);
}
```

This works even with UAC disabled (i.e. the user is a standard user and there is no convenient way for them to elevate). It also works on Windows XP, where there was no UAC convenience feature and you had to fast-user switch to run something as an administrator.

You then manifest your executable to run **asInvoker**, since you do not need administrative permissions.

---

Ask yourself:

> What would I have done on Windows XP?
>   What would I have done on Windows 7 with UAC disabled?

If they're a standard user, does your program fall over dead?