# C#: Problems connecting from a PC to an FTP through a gateway

Tags: c#, gateway

I am making a Windows Form Program where I can be able to connect to an FTP Server to download data to show it to the user. I have to make the app in a way that the user can also connect through a gateway. I made the next function to log on through a gateway:

```
private Boolean addRoute(string ip, string gw)
{
    string arg = String.Format("ADD {0} MASK 255.255.255.255 {1}", ip, gw);
    return startProcess("route.exe", arg, 10000, true);
}

private Boolean startProcess(String fileName, String arguments, int timeout, bool admin)
{
    try
    {
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        {
            //if (admin) { process.StartInfo.UserName = "admin"; }
            //process.StartInfo.UserName = "admin";
        }
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();

        if (timeout > 0)
        {
           if (process.WaitForExit(timeout))
           {
                return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           process.WaitForExit();
           return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Global.LogMessageToFile(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code works perfect with my PC but when I test it in other PC's with Windows 7 doesn't work anymore.

I thought there was a problem with the UAC permissions so I did the solution adapted to the second answer of the link [Selectively disabling UAC for specific programs on Windows Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191129/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-programatically) but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Do you have any other ideas about how can I accomplish this with the code of my program?

**EDIT** 
I have been blocked to post comments, so I will answer that I have no exceptions, and what I need is connect to a lower level, from one network to another, through a gateway. That's why I have adopted this solution.

Comment: what "doesnt work"? Any exceptions? are the relevant firewall ports opened?

Comment: What is the ExitCode from the process?