# C# Application not run on startup, Startup impact "not measured" on Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small WPF Application. I'm trying to get it started on Windows startup 
My C# code as follows:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
                {
                    key.SetValue("MyApp", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
                    key.Close();
                }
```

and deleted RegistryKey:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                key.DeleteValue("MyApp", false);
                key.Close();
            }
```

I've build one executable file (MyApp.exe) and installed on my computer. But the application still does not run when Windows start up. How can I do? how to change Startup impact "not measured" to other on Task Manager?

I'm using Windows 10 x64. Sorry for my English.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/run-the-application-at-windows-startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people who have problems like me, I have solved my problem, it is that my application needs to run as administrator so if I code as above and set **app.manifest**

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level = "requireAdministrator" UIAccess = "false "/>
```

it will not run at startup Windows.

To solve this I change my code from **CurrentUser** to **LocalMachine**:

```
 using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                key.SetValue("TechTemp", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
                key.Close();
            }
```

and

```
 using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                key.DeleteValue("TechTemp", false);
                key.Close();
            }
```

The next problem was how to turn off UAC for your application (if UAC is enabled on your computer), you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191129/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-programatically). About Status impact, your application will still run at the window startup even the state is "not measured” on Task Manager.
Thanks [Rashid Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4607649/rashid-malik) and [Sami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992165/sami)

**Update**

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191129/selectively-disabling-uac-for-specific-programs-on-windows-programatically) to run application on windows startup without adding a registry key, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add your program as a startup application:

Add this application to a special path in the Windows registry, like this:

```
private static void CreateApplicationStartup(string appName, string appPath)
{
    try
    {
        const string softwareMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRun =
            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

        using (var registryKey =
               Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(softwareMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionRun, true))
        {
            if (registryKey == null)
                throw new Exception("Startup registry key not found.");

            registryKey.SetValue(appName, appPath);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Add a shortcut of your program to the startup folder of Windows, like this:

```
private static void CreateShortcut(string shortcutName, string shortcutPath, string targetFileLocation)
{
    var shortcutLocation = Path.Combine(shortcutPath, shortcutName + ".lnk");
    var shell = new WshShell();
    var shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);

    shortcut.Description = ApplicationName;
    shortcut.IconLocation = PathManager.Icon;
    shortcut.TargetPath = targetFileLocation;
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

After implementing one of these approaches, your application will start after booting the Windows OS.

Please ensure that your application does not execute with administrative privileges.