# How to correctly sign an executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uac, digital-signature

I have made a little tool. It is a console application that when running on Win7 brings the UAC security prompt.
I tried to sign this EXE file in Visual Studio 2010 using the following steps:

1. Project properties
2. Signing
3. Create new key as shown below

[image]

The key file was successfully created, as you can see in the capture below.

[image]

### Issues:

File is still being blocked by the UAC security prompt. When I checked the file whether signed or not using the signtool.exe, it tells me, no signature was found.
Please correct me if I'm following the wrong steps.

[image]

Comment: For authenticode based code-signing - [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84847/465053)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assembly signing != Authenticode signing.

To authenticode sign an assembly with signtool, you'll need a code signing certificate from a trusted issuing authority.

You can then issue the following post-build command to sign your executable:

```
"signtool.exe" sign /f "$(SolutionDir)myCertificate.pfx" /p certPassword /d "description" /du "http://myinfourl" /t "http://timeserver.from.cert.authority/" $(TargetPath)
```

[Everything you need to know about Authenticode Code Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ieinternals/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing)

Comment: worked fine, also, many parameters are optional in the command above. this is what i used : 

signtool sign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword MyApp.exe

Comment: Is there no GUI way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Basically you have 2 options, using a command that you manually execute or execute via a batch file

```
signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f "D:\Source\Certificates\CodeSign.pfx" /as /p MyPassword "{path to exe}"
```

becomes a bit frustrating after a while
Better add it on your project's option page in the Build Events.

In your post build you would enter

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f "D:\Source\Certificates\CodeSign.pfx" /p MyPassword  $(TargetPath)
```

the Macro **$(TargetPath)** will be filled with the path to your compiled exe or dll.

Now each time you compile you will get a signed file.

Would look something like this:
[image: Project property page]

Comment: By the way, you can download signtool.exe from Microsoft, there are quite a few google "Window Kits Download", I use windows 10 so I'd use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!   In my case, because my path was sooo long I had to wrap the macro in quotes i.e. - "$(TargetPath)"

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that you can also sign exe and dll's using https://www.digicert.com/util/ this is a nice tool as it also allows you to trouble shoot issues with certificates