# Code signing cert for C# assembly

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-7, pfx

Can I use an SSL Certificate to sign a C# assembly?

I am new to this so be gentle. I did the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where you [create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) self-signed key and that worked fine. It appears [I only need a valid .PFX or .snk file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and I'm good to go. Is it really that simple?

.NET 4.0 on Windows 7, 64bit with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If you want your setups/applications that users download from the Internet to display you as the author, you need an [Authenticode certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359(vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Certificates have a purpose built into them. SSL certs generally have server and client identification as their purpose. Code signing has it's own purpose.

You can generate a self signed code signing cert, it does need a [few hoops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows) but of course Windows will warn people about it.