# ActiveX and CAB

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iis-7.5, activex, cab

I have created ActiveX for a test web application also I have created a cab file which store this dll. I have added the object element into the html and the cab wasnt installed, how ever when I opened the html file localy and not from the server all was ok, I am working with IE11

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559963/activex-installation-doesnt-work). Check if you did everything that was discussed there.

Also, please update your question and write what Security zone does the page get into when accessing from net and when run from local html file.