# ActiveX C# : acces to method of C# file

Tags: c#, .net, activex

I write a simple Activex (just show alert Hello World) but I can't acces to my method HelloWorld of my C# program when I call ActiveX in a my JavaScript  function

This is my C# program

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DemoCSharpActiveX
{
    [ProgId("DemoCSharpActiveX.HelloWorld")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("1c61c720-ce70-40e5-9e88-714469911fb3")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public String SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" > 

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebForm1</title>
  </head>
   <body>
       <OBJECT id="DemoCSharpActiveX" classid="clsid:1c61c720-ce70-40e5-9e88-714469911fb3" VIEWASTEXT></OBJECT>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var obj = document.DemoCSharpActiveX;
                if (obj) {
                    alert(obj.SayHello());
                } else {
                    alert("Object is not created!");
                }
            } catch (Err) {
                alert(Err.description);
            }

        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I execute my html file I get this error :

```
  Object does not support this property or method
```

Comment: Hard to guess what could be wrong, code is okay, html is okay.  Works fine when I try it.  The error message hints at DLL Hell, trying to use an old version of the assembly that didn't have the SayHello() method yet.  Re-run regasm.exe, perhaps.  Be sure to use the correct version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your ActiveX is properly registered in system and that it is properly initialized?

Your activeX does not implement `IObjectSafety` interface so IE will not run it normaly. Check  what security zone does your demo page land in and set this setting
[image: Prompt when initializing unsafe activex]

Also, you might want to look at [this example](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/best-way-deploy-activex-component-61236.aspx) and if you want install ActiveX from CAB then also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559963/activex-installation-doesnt-work)