# ActiveX control not load in windows 8.1, IE 11

Tags: c#, activex, internet-explorer-11, activexobject

I have written an activeX control which has very simple hellow world message. it is registered and working successfully on windows 8, internet explorer 10. But it is not working in Windows 8.1 Ie 11.

I have followed [THIS ARTICLE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c.aspx) and created setup msi without CAB file.When install the activex using this setup file, it is working successfully in windows 8. Then i tested it in windows 8.1 but it is not working, then what i did is try to register the activex control manually by using command prompt, then activex control is working correctly. but my requirement is to register the activex using setup file.

I have looked at IE Manage addon section and figured out my activex control is appear there in "not-available" list(which means already installed as activex control but not loaded, as i guess)

please be kind to help me to figure out why the activex not load here

Answer (score 0):

The article you mention is basically correct. But some steps are missing like implementing `IObjectSafety` or making non-admin installer or avoiding calling msiexec directly.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22570222/3245057) SO answer. You could also enabling prompting for initialization of unsafe activex by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106745/activex-c-sharp-acces-to-method-of-c-sharp-file/23109149#23109149) SO answer.