# Restart IE Browser in Administartor mode after uninstalling activex

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, activex

I have a custom c# activex control which is deployed as a cab file.

When new version of cab file is deployed in server, i have written custom code to check active version and uninstall old versions from the system.

After uninstalling activex , i need to restart IE in administrator mode for activex installation.

I have tried window.close() and window.open() in javascript, but as these cannot force the browser to reopen entirely .

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing it wrong.

Please look at [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22570222/3245057). [Here](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/best-way-deploy-activex-component-61236.aspx) is also a link how to create end deploy an activex. These are only for reference to what I will try to explain next.

I would go with non-admin activex instalations as first step. 
When implementing new/next version of acvitex I would:

- change clsid/guid of new activex (Guid("C23462DC-D6DF-4ea8-8BED-813C3B5F162F") in [2](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/best-way-deploy-activex-component-61236.aspx) reference)
- make installer (in cab) so that it will uninstall (or leave side by side) the old activex (reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22570222/3245057))
- change clsid on server side so that it will initialize and use the new version of activex (classid="clsid:..." in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22570222/3245057) reference)
- check for version of activex and display a message with msi installer just in case (when automatic installation failed)