# How to avoid "automation server can't create object" without changing the browser security settings?

Tags: activex

Recently I got the error "automation server can't create object", for which I know the solution is to add your website to trusted sites and enable the setting: "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting". But since this is a security issue, I searched for an alternative workaround but came up with nothing.
So, I am wondering if there is any other work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559963/activex-installation-doesnt-work). Check if you did everything that was discussed there.

The first thing is to implement IObjectSafety interface. Then sign the activex and installer and CAB. You might also want to look at this example [how to implement an activex](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/best-way-deploy-activex-component-61236.aspx).