# ActiveX refuses to install on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8.1, activex, internet-explorer-11

We have an ActiveX control shipped in a CAB that works on all IE versions, except IE11 :

"Setup cannot copy the file AcmeControl.ocx"

I tried changing the .INF for a non-admin ActiveX without luck. I also found out [others](https://www.pcpitstop.com/testax.asp) have the same problem.

Installing the ActiveX from an admin account actually works, but its not realistic to have all users to run admin. Also found another solution which consists of [running an MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559963/activex-installation-doesnt-work/22570222#22570222), but its more a workaround. Did anyone actually succeeded at this ?