# ActiveX Control Not Installing Automatically

Tags: c#, activex, activexobject

I have written a simple activex control in c# and created its .msi installer and packaged it in .cab file. when i runs the .msi installer by manually, it installs the activex control and works fine from browser. but when browser prompts for automatic installation, it does not gets installed.

I am using windows server 2008 64 bit and IE 11.

```
.INF

[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
AxControlsInstaller.msi=AxControlsInstaller.msi

[AxControlsInstaller.msi]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
RegisterServer=yes
clsid={1FC0D50A-4803-4f97-94FB-2F41717F558D}
FileVersion=1,0,0,0
```

I have following the following tutorial to create the control. it works till step 16 but prompts for installation after every refresh and not gets installed.

http://www.slideshare.net/yudep_apoi/steps-how-to-create-active-x-using-visual-studio-2008

**[IE setting change]**

Run ActiveX and plug-ins – Enabled

Download Signed ActiveX Control – Enabled

Script ActiveX controls marked as safe for scripting – Enabled

Download unsigned ActiveX Control – Prompt

Initialize and script ActiveX controls not mark as safe – Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559963/activex-installation-doesnt-work/22570222#22570222) question and my answer. It should be what you are looking for.

I am using msiexec to install the activex but not directly but through my own runmsi.exe file. Later I made some modifications to this approach. I went from msi installer to exe (quiet installation) and I am now referencing the exe installer directly (the following snippet was not tested but should work)

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0
[Deployment]
InstallScope=user|machine
[Setup Hooks]
install=install
[install]
run="""%EXTRACT_DIR%\simpleactivex.exe"""
```

You still have to make cab and sign everything - activex, exe installer, cab file. Use timestamp when signing as is shown in my answer. List of free timestamp authorities can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053511/3245057).