# How To Extract Public Key

Tags: code-signing, public-key

I used the following answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/201277/99344) to generate a certificate and sign my exe.

I need to give the public key to a third party.

I have .pvk and .cer files. How do I extract the public key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found some documentation that says that the .cer file only contains the public key so it is what I wanted.