# C# sign code: only 1 apps? Lifetime?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with my c# apps. After publish, My client tell me that he can't install my application because he have a bluescreen warning smartScreen.

[image]

I read about this subject and I saw that I need to Sign my code.

I'm looking how cost that and it is something like $99USD and more.

I read the [good practice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/) from microsoft about this subject but the information about:

1. How many apps I can activate with 1 sign code?
2. If I got a Ev Code sign, it is a lifetime licenses?
3. If not, after the expiration date, My software will stop working? Can I continue to install my apps on others windows without popup message?

Can you provide me link to read about it?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can sign a unlimited number of programs with a single certificate.
2. No, all certificates expire and will need to be renewed.
3. It depends, when you sign the app you can specify a "Timestamp server" (use `/tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com` with [signtool.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) for example), if you use a timestamp server when your certificate expires it will still be considered valid because it was valid at the time the app was signed. If you don't use a timestamp server the signing will only be valid till the certificate expires.

Here is a link to a SO question about [how to self sign a certificate for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows/201277#201277), the question is a little old so it uses the older `/t` switch for the timestamp instead of the newer `/tr` version.