# Why does my application cause a SmartScreen message?

Tags: c#

I make software on a regular basis for friends to use and for school tasks. I upload these executable files to my website. but when they download the software and execute it, they get this error

[image: image 1]

I understand you simply press "More info" to get around this, but is there a way to completely stop this???

I made a small project to test if it will still happen, and it does.

[image: image 2]

I haven't added any extra code, just that label. I've noticed the error only appears if the file was downloaded from the internet, or copied from an external drive. I want to make a custom installer for a game I'm planning and I don't want this coming up on the installer :/. Anyone able to help out in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't encountered this before, even prior to Windows 8/10

Comment: @MickyD - Since Windows 10, the warning is much more prominent. Prior it was just a warning, but nowadays it suggests that the unknown software is malicious and should not be installed.

Answer (score 4):

Your application needs to be *Signed*. If you are only giving this software to a few people, just tell them to click 'More info' to run your app.

If you want to distribute more widely you will need to sign your code. Check out [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx) to see how this can be done.

See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows) that could help you too.

Answer (score 3):

It is the Windows [SmartScreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen) at work and there is not much you can do about it. It would be possible to buy a certificate and sign your executable, but for freeware this is really out of scope. The smartscreen will learn over time, that your software is not dangerous, if it is installed often enough.

The warning is not related to VisualStudio projects, it affects any new released executable.

Actually I support the idea of SmartScreen to protect users, but it should not depend on a certificate, which can be bought by developers.