# Set editor when UAC prompt

Tags: c#, windows, uac

I'm writing a program in C # that needs administrator rights. To do this, I added the following lines to the "app.manifest" file:

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

The request is working properly The program has administrator rights.

My problem is that on demand, the publisher is unknown and I do not know how to change it.
[UAC image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW7EP.jpg)

I entered my name in the assembly, but it does not change anything.

Does anyone know how to change this value?

Comment: It needs to be code signed in order to have something other than Unknown in the UAC prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I think I can follow this method ? [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84bc2159-d646-4de5-9908-2e82a4239df1/how-can-i-digitally-sign-my-c-application-?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Yes that method will allow signing with a self-signed certificate; however if you want to ensure that the publisher is known, then you need to use a purchased code signing certificate.

Answer (score 1):

source: https://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/programming/59673-uac-message-publisher-unknown

In the above source a similar question is asked. The responses indicate the use of a **codesigning certificate**. There is also a mention to a how to in stackoverflow that explains how to create your own codesigning certificate: [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)