# Kernel Mode Driver Signing using Self Signed Certificates

Tags: certificate, openssl, digital-signature, driver, self-signed

Can anyone help me in signing the .sys files for windows 7 64 bits? I have created the self signed certificates using Openssl and I want to sign the the .sys files with that certificates using signTool.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this process by following the [Life saving Link :D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)

Thanks [Roger Lipscombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8446/roger-lipscombe), [DBolton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8786837/dbolton) and all those who visited :p