# Unverified Publisher Warning still occurs after Code Signing

Tags: code-signing-certificate

I am new to code signing. My goal is to be able to sign a setup.exe generated by Visual Studio and install it on my Windows 7 PC and my friends' Windows PCs without triggering  unverified publisher or other warnings. The following approach did not work. What other steps do I need to take to achieve this?

On Windows 7, I followed the Original Answer at
[How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows/201277#201277) by completing following steps.
 - created & imported CA
 - created SPC & converted to PFX
 - used first signtool command to sign a setup.exe generated by Visual Studio 2015.

The Digital Signatures General tab now says the "The digital signature is OK". But running the setup.exe on my Windows 7 PC triggers an Application Install Security Warning which says "The publisher cannot be verified. Are you sure you want to install this application?".