# Why signtool.exe very slow with self signed code certificate?

Tags: c#, certificate, digital-signature, code-signing, signtool

I try to generate certificate from

[How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows?rq=1)

When using signtool wnd tested it with a list of available timestamp here:
https://gist.github.com/Manouchehri/fd754e402d98430243455713efada710

It took (5 - 10) minutes for sign.
a DLL have few classes only.

Should I use timestamp with non-official self-signed code certificates?
Or ignore timestamp for generated self-signed certificates? I know that purchased certificates must use timestamp.

**Edit:**

I still have problem. Anyone can help please :(

Comment: `5 - 10` minutes seem more a timeout then actually signing, never takes more than a couple milliseconds - did your dll actually get signed or do you run in a timeout?

Comment: Its signed but after 5 minutes. I tried with turn off firewall, restart connection, etc. But something strange... I might think because its self-signed certificate not purchased one. But am not sure about that. What timeserver you 100% preferred or used.  I use following

http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp

Comment: we are using http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode but don't ask me why, maybe it first in google - sorry, if no timeout, I can't help you further would not know any reason behind it

Comment: @Rand Random, I switched to sectigo link you provided Thanks a lot for that. Its improved much in time. But still taking 1 minute per DLL... Time stamping is a huge deal...

Comment: I mean not few seconds like normal usage you mentioned , So improve is good also :)